# wifi not working ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, wireless, broadcom

Hi I just installed ubuntu 16.04 with third party stuff has well but once finished I dont see any option to enable wifi in desktop menu or in settings

Also, i won't be able to connect to ethernet 
Any fix for this thanks

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: ok i did that thing

Comment: what next do i do?

Comment: You did not do that thing.

Comment: what thing i typed it into computer

Comment: Please read the first comment again ;-)

Comment: ok done i dit it

Comment: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/286416184583258112/324520222394417152/image.jpg)

Comment: i got error i attached  [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/286416184583258112/324523902028087296/image.jpg)

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` Where is the `*`?

Comment: sorry works now